# $N \unlhd G$ if and only if $gSg^{-1} \subset N$ for all $g \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $N$ be a finite subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$, i.e. $N = \langle S \rangle$. Show that $N \unlhd G$ if and only if
$gSg^{-1} \subset N$ for all $g \in G$. Next also assume that $G$ is generated by $T$, i.e. $G = \langle T \rangle$. Now show that $N \unlhd G$ if and only if
$tSt^{-1} \subset N$ for all $t \in T$.

MY PROOF:
Since $N=\langle S\rangle$ is normal in $G=\langle T\rangle$, it must follow that $gS^ag^{-1} \in G$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g \in G$. It therefore follows that $s^a \in N$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since each $s^a \in N < G$ and all t $\in G$, it must follow that $tSt^{-1} \in N$.

I feel like I am missing something critical...

Comment: Your argument indeed misses a lot. To show that $N$ is normal you need to show that $gng^{-1}$ lies in $N$ for every $n\in N$, not that $gs^ag^{-1}$ lies in $G$ for every $s\in S$ and every integer $a$. Note also that not every element of $N$ needs to be a power of an element of $S$: that's not what "generated by" means. Finally, I'm afraid that the final thing you are being asked to prove is actually **false**. You also need to assume that $t^{-1}St\subseteq N$ for every $t\in T$.

Comment: (Also, "$tSt^{-1}\in N$" doesn't even make sense: $N$ is a subgroup, so its elements are, well, elements; but $tSt^{-1}$ is a *subset*: a collection of elements. So it makes no sense to say that this subset of $G$ is an *element* of $N$)